# Can i use word "Free" in my appname for appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I uploaded an app to Appstore with name containing word "FREE".I faced rejection due to 3 reasons. One of them was

> “Your app name, subtitle, icons, screenshots, or previews to be displayed on the App Store include references to the price of your app or the service it provides, which is not considered a part of these metadata items.”

i really want to use that name. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is  not about programming.

Comment: go ahead mister

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue couple of months ago with one of my app. Apple doesn't allow using the word 'Free' in app name, screenshots or previews from March 2017.
What I did was, I made the 'Free' version let's say 'ABC free' to 'ABC' and made the paid version to 'ABC Pro'. Moreover I would recommend you to go with in-app model rather than free/pro versions.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is no longer allowing developers to include pricing information in the name of their respective app store submissions, a practice commonly used to promote free or inexpensive software.

Apple has been gradually shifting App Store policy over the past month to accommodate the new stipulations, according to VentureBeat. In particular, submissions containing references to pricing in their name, preview images or metadata are being blocked from the iOS and Mac App Stores.

Apple's current developer guidelines do not specifically restrict developers from including the term "Free" in app names, though certain documentation does prohibit similar information from appearing in app screenshots. Appearing alongside app descriptions, screenshots are often modified with text to promote or highlight app features.

"Dont reference specific prices in your app screenshots. Referencing a local currency can mislead customers in other store territories and cause confusion," the document reads.

For more information, have a look at [appleinsider](http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/03/28/apple-rejecting-app-submissions-with-names-that-include-references-to-price).

Comment: Really Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As you now know that Apple don't allow the use of such phrase in App name, you should try something really **creative** to be able to use such phrases. Try creating a name using **synonym** or some other **phrase** of the word **"Free"** which some how **do not sound like Free!** :D That way you might pass through the review process.

Try your luck.

Comment: Really Helpful.